# how to use @font-face for supported browser and Cufon for the others

Tags: fonts, font-face, cufon, modernizr

I'm using HTML5 Boilerplate and I have to use a custom font.

So, I can obviously use @font-face but what about old browsers? Maybe I can use Cufon, but only in these cases and not even for browsers that support @font-face instead.

So I'm wondering what is the best approach to use @font-face for supported browser and Cufon for the others?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the SVG format support, [LOFFS](https://github.com/Mouvedia/lack-of-font-face-support-detection) is a perfect solution for you.